# Mongoose - How to do many intricate relations? Specific quick challenge example request included below. Thanks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I know how to use sequelize with node, angular, express etc... but I am just starting to learn the M part of the mean stack using mongoose. The problem is that I don't know what mongodb is capable of in terms of organizing data in the database.

Could someone who has done complex relations in mongodb/mongoose be so kind as to show me the following?:

I would like to see a simple, made up, easy to understand SCHEMA for the following scenario.

1) Users have many friends (meaning an array of friends which are also user object instances).

2) Users can attend many events (users will have an attendance status for each event, i.e. attending or declined). Users will have properties for a name and a username as well.

3) Events can have many users (and each user will have an attendance status). Events will also have properties for a time, and a place.

That's pretty much it. Again, if someone could write out the SCHEMA for this, I would be very thankful, as I am trying to understand

Answer (score 0):

No offence, but letting someone else write your schema doesn't help you much in terms of understanding the M part of the stack.
I would really advise you to buy the book [MongoDB: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344682).

This gives you a good insight into Mongo and also has a part about embedding or referencing documents. This really comes down to how you work with your data, and how much the data changes.

Simple mongoose sample:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    friends: [UserSchema],
    events : [{
       event_id : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
       status : { type : Number}] 
})

var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : { type: String},
    users : [UserSchema]
})
```

This is a real basic example, where one contains a single ref (EventSchema.users / UserSchema.friend) and a bit like hybrid solution UserSchema.events which contains the id of the event and some basic information.

In mongoose you can use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to retrieve the related documents.

But i like to stress out, go buy the book and read it, so you can make the right choice for your scenario!

Comment: Having someone write "my schema" is not happening. I am not even using this schema I just figure it's a simple intricate relational data example and wanted to see it in action, as I have not used mongoose yet. Thank you I will check the book out.

Comment: @Tyler in your question you mention a couple of things which have impact on the schema design. Mostly to embed or reference the related documents, or even use a hybrid approach. It's therefor not easy to write something you could use 1:1. Therefore i mentioned the book, which is a good read and gives some insights about which approaches you could use. I'll update my answer with a "sample" ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the example! Very helpful. If I am reading it correctly, there may be a missing "}" before the 'events' array closes?

Comment: @Tyler yeah sorry placed it outta my Head 

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to achieve this but its all up to your database design and how you want to access the data. Typically for groups and events im quite fond of having a collection which just has a ref to a user and to an event, as well as extra data you may require. As for storing friends in mongo, you could either store as an array of user ID refs or thr same style as groups/events. Take a look at population in mongoose and schema properties (Also I'm not sure asking people a challenge question that is clearly what you have to do is a great solution)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This isn't what I have to do, I could've use any other schema example. I just want to see it happening in action as I've not used mongoose/mongo much yet. So anyways, what you're talking about is essentially a "join" collection, in a way?